# Knn prediction going 100% on y_test

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, knn, iris-dataset

I'm trying to implement K-nearest neighbors on Iris dataset but after doing the predictions, yhat goes 100% without errors, there must have something wrong and i have no idea what it is...

I created a column named class_id, where i changed:

- setosa = 1.0
- versicolor = 2.0
- virginica = 3.0

that column is type float.

### Getting X an Y

```
    x = df[['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width']].values
```

type(x) shows nparray

```
    y = df['class_id'].values
```

type(y) shows nparray

### Normalizing data

```
    x = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(x).transform(x.astype(float))
```

### Creating train and test

```
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
```

### Checking best K value:

```
    Ks = 12
    for i in range(1,Ks):
       k = i
       neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k).fit(x_train,y_train)
       yhat = neigh.predict(x_test)
       score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,yhat)
       print('K: ', k, ' score: ', score, '\n')
```

### Result:

K:  1  score:  0.9666666666666667

K:  2  score:  1.0

K:  3  score:  1.0

K:  4  score:  1.0

K:  5  score:  1.0

K:  6  score:  1.0

K:  7  score:  1.0

K:  8  score:  1.0

K:  9  score:  1.0

K:  10  score:  1.0

K:  11  score:  1.0

### Printing y_test and yhat WITH K = 5

```
    print(yhat)
    print(y_test)
```

### Result:

yhat: [2. 1. 3. 2. 2. 1. 2. 3. 2. 2. 3. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 3. 2. 2. 3. 1. 3. 1. 3.
3. 3. 3. 3. 1. 1.]

y_test: [2. 1. 3. 2. 2. 1. 2. 3. 2. 2. 3. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 3. 2. 2. 3. 1. 3. 1. 3.
3. 3. 3. 3. 1. 1.]

all of them shouldn't be 100% correct, there must be something wrong

Comment: You are making use of the `iris` dataset. It's a well cleaned and model dataset. The features have a strong correlation to the result which results in the `kNN` model fitting the data really well. To test this you can reduce the size of the training set and this will results in a drop in the accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with the explanation of skillsmuggler(user):

> You are making use of the iris dataset. It's a well cleaned and model
>   dataset. The features have a strong correlation to the result which
>   results in the kNN model fitting the data really well. To test this
>   you can reduce the size of the training set and this will results in a
>   drop in the accuracy.

Prediction model was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a confusion matrix. Test every example of your test data, and check metrics of the specificity, sensibility, accuracy and precision. 
[image: confusion matrix]

where:

```
TN = True Negative
FN = False Negative
FP = False Positive
TP = True Positive
```

Here you can check what is the difference between specificity and sensibility
https://dzone.com/articles/ml-metrics-sensitivity-vs-specificity-difference

Here you have one example about how you can get one confusion matrix in python using sklearn.

Also try to make a ROC Curve (optional)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic

Comment: The thing is that even with confusion matrix is goes 100% accuracy rate and I'm not sure how or why...

Comment: read it please: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Multiclass_Confusion_Matrix_Explanation